# What is P(X=k) with X the total number of games played

Tags: probability

Two people (A and B) play a game A wins with probability p and B with probability 1-p.
A player only wins when he wins 2 consecutive games.
Assume that X is the total number of games played. What is P(X=k)?

I thougt the probability of winning 2 consecutive games is $p.p+(1-p)(1-p)=2p^2-2p+1$ and the poisson parameter is $k(2p^2-2p+1)$ thus

$P(X=k)=e^{-k(2p^2-2p+1)}\frac{(k(2p^2-2p+1))^k}{(2p^2-2p+1)!}$
Is this right?

Comment: Make a good distinction between "winning" and "winning a game"

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Event $\{X=5\}$ can be described as: $ABABB\vee BABAA$

Event $\{X=6\}$ can be described as: $ABABAA\vee BABABB$

Et cetera.